# How to transform an array of one value into an object in $project stage?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Using mongodb, I would like to transform an array in a a document that looks like this:

```
{activities: [{"start": start_date, "end": end_date, value:"4332A"}]}
```

Into an object, like this (only projecting the value field as the value of "activities"):

```
{activities: "4332A"}
```

I have tried using $arrayToObject in the $project stage, but the results is not really what  I am looking for :

```
    db.companies.aggregate([{
        $project: {
            $map: {
                'input': '$activities',
                'as': 'item',
                'in': {
                    'k': 'activities',
                    'v': '$$item.value'
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

The output being:

```
{"activities": {"activities": "4332A"}}
```

Comment: will there always be just one value in the array?

Comment: Yes, the preprocessing applied before transforms the "activities" field in an array with only one start_date, end_date and value.

Comment: What is the "preprocessing" ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is always exactly one result in the array ( as you said ), you can just use [arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/), like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      activities: {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$activities.value",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-iztFnllykr)